# How do I change a working dirrectory for created folder using python?

Tags: python

I want to create folder named by date in a selected folder. After that I want to make created folder a working directory. I got stucked with os.path.dirname as workingDirrectory apparently excludes \ARSOFinalTest from the path. Why is it so?

```
delovnaMapa = r"C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\ARSOFinalTest"
print(delovnaMapa)
today = datetime.now()
dateAndTime = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
os.mkdir(delovnaMapa + "/" + dateAndTime)
workingDirrectory = os.path.dirname(delovnaMapa) + "/" + dateAndTime
print(workingDirrectory)
os.chdir(workingDirrectory)
```

Results:

```
C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\ARSOFinalTest
C:\Users\Tim\Desktop/2022-10-30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-34-84fcb92484cb>", line 8, in <module>
    os.chdir(workingDirrectory)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\Tim\\Desktop/2022-10-30'
```

Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: Your Python script can't change its caller's working directory. If that's what you are trying to do, you need a different approach.

Comment: to add more, I would also recommend you change `"/"` to `"\\"` to append the correct slash character to your path. The latter one is using one backslash to protect the second one

Comment: @Alex.Kh "/" *is* unusual but correct, even on Windows.

Comment: @Sören thanks, it's good to know. I always thought otherwise

Comment: Why would the parameter to `chdir()` be anything different from the call to `mkdir()` that created the directory?

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, that's what dirname does. Let's have a look at the docs:

[os.path.dirname](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname)

> Return the directory name of pathname path. This is the first element of the pair returned by passing path to the function split().

[os.path.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split)

> Split the pathname path into a pair, (head, tail) where tail is the last pathname component and head is everything leading up to that. [...]

So, yes, os.path.dirname will remove the last component, in your case ARSOFinalTest, from it's argument. You don't want that, so just leave it out!

```
workingDirrectory = delovnaMapa + "/" + dateAndTime
```